# GridSearchCV eliminate output

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I use GridSearchCV to get best parameters but it gave me thousands of rows of outputs. How can I eliminate this output or suppress it from the code  "grid.fit(X_train,y_train)"

```
param_grid = {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],'C':[0.001,.009,0.01,.09,1,5,10,25]}
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(),param_grid,refit=True,verbose=2,cv=5)
grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you share what you mean by lines of output (give an example of one line?). If I understand you correctly, you might want to change verbose argument to 0)

Comment: Yes that is right thank you but this time I get warnings how can I eliminate that?Thanks

Comment: Ok so it depends on the warnings but now that we know what the problem is, those are not outputs that you are getting, it's just GridSearchCV printing out it's process for you to inspect (if you were so inclined). Check out the documentation for GridSearchCV (specifically the verbose parameter) and set it to be as specific as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to only print the best parameters, add

> print(grid.fit(X_train,Y_train).best_estimator_)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30618740)